# JQuery UI accordion is slow in IE 8

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, performance

I have a web application screen with number of dynamically created JQuery UI accordions. I am looping through the incoming JSON string and dynamically create the accordions as follows.

```
for (i in json.panels) {

   var accordionName = json.panels[i].panelName;
   var isExpanded = json.panels[i].expand;
   var activeProperty = (isExpanded) ? 0 : false;

   var accordElemId = "accordion_"+i;
   var accordDiv = '<div id="' + accordElemId + '"></div>';
   var accordion = $("#"+accordElemId );

   var startTime = new Date().getTime();

   accordion.accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: "content",
      active: activeProperty,
      animated : false
   });

    var endTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("Time for "+accordionName+"="+(endTime - startTime));

}
```

Then i compared the time to create each accordion in IE8 and IE10

in IE8 i found its really slow and when i navigate through pages the performance is continuously degrade.
please have a look at following figures, time is in milliseconds.

1)

```
LOG: ----------------------------start -------------------------------------
LOG: Time for Patient Address =  16
LOG: Time for Current Legal Status =  32
LOG: Time for Alerts and Risk Factors =  0
LOG: Time for Current Wards/Programs =  16
LOG: Time for Open Orders =  0
LOG: Time for RAI-MH Form =  0
LOG: Time for RAI =  16
LOG: Time for OCAN-C =  31
LOG: Time for LD =  0
LOG: --- Diff create ajaxURL =  0
LOG: ----------------------------end -------------------------------------
```

2)

```
LOG: ----------------------------start -------------------------------------
LOG: Time for Patient Address =  16
LOG: Time for Current Legal Status =  47
LOG: Time for Alerts and Risk Factors =  32
LOG: Time for Current Wards/Programs =  16
LOG: Time for Open Orders =  15
LOG: Time for RAI-MH Form =  110
LOG: Time for RAI =  140
LOG: Time for OCAN-C =  141
LOG: Time for LD =  31
LOG: --- Diff create ajaxURL =  0
LOG: ----------------------------end -------------------------------------
```

3)

```
LOG: ----------------------------start -------------------------------------
LOG: Time for Patient Address =  62
LOG: Time for Current Legal Status =  485
LOG: Time for Alerts and Risk Factors =  15
LOG: Time for Current Wards/Programs =  219
LOG: Time for Open Orders =  391
LOG: Time for RAI-MH Form =  62
LOG: Time for RAI =  250
LOG: Time for OCAN-C =  391
LOG: Time for LD =  110
LOG: --- Diff create ajaxURL =  0
LOG: ----------------------------end -------------------------------------
```

Then i tried IE 10 and it super fast and it is consistent with the performance

```
----------------------------start ------------------------------------- 
Time for Patient Address =  7 
Time for Current Legal Status =  5 
Time for Alerts and Risk Factors =  5 
Time for Current Wards/Programs =  6 
Time for Open Orders =  6 
Time for RAI-MH Form =  6 
Time for RAI =  4 
Time for OCAN-C =  4 
Time for LD =  4 
--- Diff create ajaxURL =  0 
----------------------------end ------------------------------------
```

Do you guys have any idea about this? appreciate you help

Thanks,
Keth